# Cache few columns but write all of them

Tags: ignite

I have recently started exploring Apache ignite for one of our project. I have a requirement, I want to cache few columns of a table in memory, and update(or insert a new row) all the columns but still be able to cache only few of them.

Let me take an example to explain:

```
TABLE_A:
COLUMN_A - varchar
COLUMN_B - integer
COLUMN_C - blob
```

In the above example table, I want to cache only COLUMN_A and COLUMN_B in memory and omit COLUMN_C from caching but when I update or insert a row I should be able to populate all of the columns(including COLUMN_C, I am getting the data from an external source for updating/overwriting the row) but still be able to cache only columns A and B. Please note that I am doing this to save some memory because COLUMN_C is a huge object.

Additionally, I also want to get COLUMN_C on-demand from DB.

I tried a hack with custom JdbcTypesTransformer, it is great for pre loading only A & B columns (not C), but as soon as I insert or update a row by setting column C, C also gets populated in cache.

Please suggest me a way to do this in Apache Ignite.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this, and frankly I would not recommend to do this. If `COLUMN_C` doesn't need to be cached, just remove it from your objects and update it separately instead of updating through Ignite. This approach is cleaner and is going to be more efficient as well. Persistence store is update by Ignite server node, so you will end up transferring `COLUMN_C` value to the server node first, and if it's huge, that's a bad idea.